# Internal and External link search broken in org 9.3

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Links seem to be broken in org-mode 9.3

```org
[[link-to-text]]
[[*link-to-heading]]
[[file:path/to/file::*heading]]
[[file:path/to/file::search-string]]
```

The following searches all bring point to the beginning of the buffers in question, without moving to the searched header or text.

I suspect this has something to do with this change over [here](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html):

> Version 9.3 Incompatible changes Change bracket link escaping syntax
>
> Org used to percent-encode sensitive characters in the URI part of the
>   bracket links.
>
> Now, escaping mechanism uses the usual backslash character, according
>   to the following rules, applied in order:
>
> ```
> All consecutive \ characters at the end of the link must be escaped;
> Any ] character at the very end of the link must be escaped;
> All consecutive \ characters preceding ][ or ]] patterns must be escaped;
> Any ] character followed by either [ or ] must be escaped;
> Others ] and \ characters need not be escaped.
> ```
>
> When in doubt, use the function org-link-escape in order to turn a
>   link string into its properly escaped form.

Can someone explain this to me?

---

## The buggy code:

The buggy code is this:

```
(use-package mandoku
  :config
  (setq mandoku-base-dir "~/krp")
  (setq mandoku-repositories-alist '(("KR" "http://www.kanripo.org/api/v1.0")))
  (defvar mandoku-starter-packages
  (list
  'magit
    'json
    'org 'org-plus-contrib
    'mandoku 'mandoku-meta-kr 'mandoku-meta-zb
    )
  "Libraries that should be installed by default."))
```

The customized link used by mandoku, [[mandoku:meta:KR2a0007:10]] seems to be interfering with the normal functioning of org-mode links that do text search within buffers.

Comment: All the searches work fine for me: note however that a link like `[[search]]` will search for a string like `<<search>>` in the buffer (if it does not find it, it will ask whether to create it as a heading). `[[*link-to-heading]]` will search for a heading like this: `*** link-to-heading` at any level and similarly for the file-type links. I cannot reproduce the problem you are seeing: you might want to single-step through the function `org-link-open` in [edebug](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Edebug.html#Edebug), although that's probably the last resort.

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to fix the situation.

Comment: BTW, the text you quoted has nothing to do with these links: if you pass each one to `org-link-escape`, it is returned unchanged. What you quoted has to do with the (messy) situation in `http` links.

Comment: Yes - I know... I think I need to figure out a way to instrument the source code for edebug to work properly.

Comment: You should probably forget that I suggested `edebug`. Have you tried starting emacs with the `-q` option in order to bypass your init file? If not, that's probably a good thing to try.

Comment: Hmm.... The links worked in `emacs -q`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106515/discussion-between-nickd-and-sati).